# VAR independent variables?

Tags: vector-autoregression

I need some clarification: Is it correct that when applying a VAR or VARMA model, there is only dependent variables? for example you will have a dependent variable X_t and dependent variable Y_t. Thus, there is no independent variables included in the data set.

Comment: Hi: It's probably best to say that, in a VAR, all variables are endogenous.  The terms "dependent" and "independent are terms used in classical regression in order to differentiate between the LHS and RHS of the equations but that concept doesn't really apply in a VAR because all of the variables are on both sides.

Comment: I see thank you, my book refers to them as dependent variables as they are dependent in each of their equations :)

Comment: Hi Gus. yes. I don't think that's a good usage because each variable in a VAR is dependent on all of the others. Or atleast that's the assumption. For a good but lengthy and detailed explanation of VARS, I recommend lutkepohl but it's not something to be read in a day, week or even month.